# HTC Sensation isn't recognized in Linux for Debugging

Tags: android, linux, ubuntu, adb

I'm using the Eclipse IDE.

I can only see question marks in the Android Device Chooser; where I'd usually find numbers. it's like I didn't add udev rules for the device

I tried with an HTC Inspire and it worked fine, logcat also worked fine but not with this newer Handset.

It works fine on windows but i prefer developing on linux; Ubuntu 11.04 to be more specific

this is my output from $lsusb

```
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 09da:054f A4 Tech Co., Ltd 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bb4:0c86 High Tech Computer Corp.   //THIS IS THE ONE!!
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0c45:62c0 Microdia Sonix USB 2.0 Camera
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

and Here's the contents of my "rules" file a.k.a. $sudo gedit /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb_device", SYSFS{idVendor}=="0bb4", MODE="0666"
```

I don't understand why it works fine with the older HTC handset but not with this newer one.

Comment: is it set for debugging?

Comment: yes, it works fine with Eclipse and logcat on my windows pc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i got this help from XDA developers forum

i just added these few lines to my `/etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules` and I was wired in :D

```
#HTC Sensation
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", SYSFS{idVendor}=="0bb4", MODE="0666"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb",ATTR{idVendor}=="0bb4",ATTR{idProduct}=="0c86",SYMLINK+="android_adb"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb",ATTR{idVendor}=="0bb4",ATTR{idProduct}=="0c86",SYMLINK+="android_fastboot"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
cd android-sdk-linux/platform-tools
sudo su
./adb kill-server
./adb start-server
```